# Перевод данных в base64

Tags: c#

Допустим есть массив из 4 чисел. Мне нужно перевести их в base64 но вообще можно и в HEX. Что в принципе не суть. Дело в том что мне нужно что бы код не сам выбрал сколько байт занимают эти числа. А самому определить в скольких количествах байт будет храниться число. В моём конкретном случае это 2, 2, 4, 4 байт. Допустим я создам массив интов. Как выдать каждому число то количество байт для хранения сколько я хочу? Или для этого лучше воспользоваться не массивом а списком?

вот допустим мой пример. Как выдать каждому число то количество байт сколько я хочу?

```
List<object> list = new List<object>() { 128, 15, 25, 175 }; 
string[] sList = new string[4]; 
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{ 
  sList[i] = Convert.ToString(list[i], 16); 
}
```

И ещё такой вопрос. В моём примере не хочет работать конвертация в hex. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Устраивает хекс? ну так используйте обычное преобразование в тот тип данных, который позволит не потерять точность, и при этом имеет строго требуемый размер. Если такого нет - изобретите собственный. *В моём конкретном случае это 2, 2, 4, 4 байт. Допустим я создам массив интов.* - создайте массив из трёх 4-байтных интов, и упакуйте в первый элемент два первых числа: a[0]=x[0]+x[1]*256*256. Или наоборот, массив из 6 двухбайтных или 12 байтовых, и раскидайте значения по ним.

Comment: Выбирай тогда вручную

Comment: Массиву интов будет Выдано строго то количество бит, которое предполагает инт. Если Вам требуется хранить разные типы, то нужен тип object и список например.

Comment: @Dejsving вот допустим мой пример. Как выдать каждому число то количество байт сколько я хочу? `List<object> list = new List<object>() { 128, 15, 25, 175 };

            string[] sList = new string[4];

            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                sList[i] = Convert.ToString(list[i], 16);
            }` И ещё такой вопрос. В моём примере не хочет работать конвертация в hex. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @Андрей Что за формулировки? "Не хочет работать конвертация в hex." - так прямо и заявляет Вам: "Не хочу работать!"?

Answer (score 0):

Метод [`string Convert.ToBase64String(Byte[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

Преобразования в байты с чисел разных размеров занимается [BitConvert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int[] a = new int[4] {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003}; //Ваш массив
byte[] binData = new byte[2+2+4+4];
BitConvert.GetBytes((ushort)a[0]).CopyTo(binData, 0); //Копируем в начало
BitConvert.GetBytes((ushort)a[1]).CopyTo(binData, 2); //Копируем со смещением 2
BitConvert.GetBytes((uint)a[2]).CopyTo(binData, 4);//Копируем со смещением 2+2
BitConvert.GetBytes((uint)a[3]).CopyTo(binData, 8);//Копируем со смещением 2+2+4
string BASE64 = Convert.ToBase64String(binData); //Получаем base64
```

Comment: Да спасибо у меня есть и такой вариант.

Comment: `List<object> list = new List<object>() { 128, 15, 25, 175 };

            string[] sList = new string[4];

            byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(list[i]);
                sList[i] = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            }`

Comment: Но я ещё хочу понять как сразу в hex. И при всём при этом, мне нужно самому выделать количество байт на хранение каждому числу. А не столько сколько оно реально занимает. И ещё вопрос в догонку. Вот я перевёл лист object в байт допустим. Как вывести на экран сколько каждое число заняло байт?

Comment: А чтотакое 0, 2, 4, 8 ?

Comment: и что такое a? Массив инт в котором храняться мои числа? или что? не совсем понятно откуда это берётся. Можно поподробнее?

Comment: a - Ваш массив интов. 0, 2, 4, 8 это с какого места помещать полученную информацию в массив. Выше: new byte[число] - это сколько бит вам требуется. 2+2+4+4 нагляднее, хотя система сама сложит и откомпилирует уже с результатом сложения

Comment: @Dejsving а преобразования к шортам и интам для чего тут? Если уже и так расписано по сколько байт брать на каждое число? И мой вопрос второй. Как вывести количество байт для каждого числа. Ну скольк ооно занимает? Это как то можно посмотреть?

Comment: @Андрей чтоб `BitConvert.GetBytes` знал сколько байт ему надо получить! `ushort` - целое положительное 2 байта, `uint` - целое положительное 4 байта.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение Дмитрий. А как то же сделать в hex? Так же назначить каждому интовскому числу столько байт сколько я хочу, и перевести их в hex?

Comment: @Андрей поподробнее, чего Вы хотите?

Comment: Ну допустим у меня есть массив `int[] mas = new int[4] { 128, 15, 25, 175 };` Я хочу его перевести в hex. Но опять же не так что бы инт сам им выдал столько байт сколько реально занимает каждое число. А что бы я сам по той же схеме выдал каждому числу количество в которых оно будет храниться.

Comment: @Андрей HEX это представление числа и не более того, что значит "я сам по той же схеме выдал каждому числу" 15 будет 0xF и в 2 байтах и в 4 и в 8 и в 16! Что Вы имеете ввиду? что Вы хотите???

Answer (score 0):

Ниже универсальное решение без проверки переполнения.

Автор, было бы здорово - понять, для чего ты это хочешь делать и с какими данными работаешь. Из описания твоей задачи я могу сделать вывод, что тебе скорее нужно записывать стандартные типы данных: Byte, Int16, Int32, Int64, и в этом случае вопрос - зачем все эти извращения, и почему бы просто не использовать [BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) в связке с [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx), или, если данные типизированы, не описать их в структурах для последующего мапинга на массив байт (или маршалинга).

```
public static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    long[] numbers = {128, 15, 25, 175, 7};
    int[] sizes = {2, 2, 4, 4, 9};

    if (numbers.Length != sizes.Length)
        throw new InvalidDataException("numbers.Length != size.Length");

    if (numbers.Length < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Empty array");
        return;
    }

    int bufferSize = 0;
    foreach (var size in sizes)
    {
        if (size < 1)
            throw new InvalidDataException($"Invalid size: {size}");
        bufferSize += size;
    }

    int position = 0;
    byte[] buff = new byte[bufferSize];
    byte[] integerBuffer = new byte[sizeof(long)];

    fixed (byte* integerPtr = integerBuffer)
    fixed (byte* buffPtr = buff)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            long number = numbers[i];
            int desiredSize = sizes[i];
            int size = Math.Min(desiredSize, sizeof(long));
            int paddingSize = desiredSize - size;

            *(long*)integerPtr = number;

            for (int n = 0; n < size; n++)
                buffPtr[position++] = integerPtr[n];

            if (paddingSize > 0)
            {
                byte padding = number < 0 ? byte.MaxValue : byte.MinValue;
                for (int n = 0; n < paddingSize; n++)
                    buffPtr[position++] = padding;
            }
        }
    }

    string result = Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```